# How to prevent multiple fire event on single element

Tags: jquery, html

my problem is i load content section through ajax in, content section also have script once they load work properly but next time they load then every jquery event work multiple time my content section code as below

```
<script>

    /*add education section*/
    $('body').on('click','.add-education-detail',function (e) {

         e.stopImmediatePropagation();
         e.preventDefault();

         if(! confirm('Are you Sure ?')) {

             return false;
         }
         html = ' <div class="row card-body">\n' +
             '            <div class="col-md-6 ">\n' +
             '                <div class="form-group row">\n' +
             '                    <div class="col-sm-10">\n' +
             '                        <input type="text" name = "education[]" class="form-control" size="7" placeholder="Enter Education" required></input>\n' +
             '                    </div>\n' +
             '                </div>\n' +
             '                <div class="form-group row">\n' +
             '                    <div class="col-sm-10">\n' +
             '                        <input type="text" name = "class[]" class="form-control" size="7" placeholder="Enter Class"></input>\n' +
             '                    </div>\n' +
             '                </div>\n' +
             '                <div class="form-group row">\n' +
             '                    <div class="col-sm-10">\n' +
             '                        <input type="text" name = "passing_year[]" class="form-control" size="7" placeholder="Enter Passing Year"></input>\n' +
             '                    </div>\n' +
             '                </div>\n' +
             '            </div>\n' +
             '            <div class="col-md-6">\n' +
             '                <div class="form-group row">\n' +
             '                    <div class="col-sm-10">\n' +
             '                        <input type="text" name = "percentage[]" class="form-control" size="7" placeholder="Enter Percentage"></input>\n' +
             '                    </div>\n' +
             '                </div>\n' +
             '                <div class="form-group row">\n' +
             '                    <div class="col-sm-10">\n' +
             '                        <input type="text" name = "bourd_university[]" class="form-control" size="7" placeholder="Enter Board/University"></input>\n' +
             '                    </div>\n' +
             '                </div>\n' +
             '                 <div class="form-group row">\n' +
             '                    <div class="col-sm-10">\n' +
             '                            <a class="btn btn-danger delete-education-detail">Remove</a>\n' +
             '                    </div>\n' +
             '                </div>'+
             '            </div>\n' +
             '        </div>';


        $('#education-detail-section').append(html);
        total_education(1);

        });




</script>
```

and the html as already have on master but the script is loaded as a content ,

Comment: `add-education-detail` is class of what element?

Comment: What does the function `total_education(1);` do??

Comment: @LinkinTED  they count dynamic added element on dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `off()` you can prevent event handlers to attach them multi-pal times.

```
$('body').off().on('click','.add-education-detail',function (e) {
   // Your other code
});
```